# ng-bootstrap modal TypeError in promise

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am using @ng-bootstrap in angular 4 app.

I am able to open a modal instance and was able to pass data to modal.
on modal close i was able to get results from modal.

The issue i am facing is i tried to assign the result with some existing variable inside the parent component where the modal is used.
But it's showing below error.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Below is the code i have written to show modal

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminService } from "../admin.service";
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons, NgbAlertConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgAddModalComponent } from './add-modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name-list',
  templateUrl: './name-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./name-list.component.css'],
  providers: [NgbAlertConfig]
})
export class NameListComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  name: string;
  nameList: [];

  constructor(private adminService: AdminService, private modalService: NgbModal) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.adminService.getNamelist()
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.nameList = res.name; //["john", "smith", "todd"]
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

   onAddClick() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgAddModalComponent, {size: 'lg'});//To open Modal
        modalRef.componentInstance.name = this.name;//To send data to Modal
        modalRef.result.then((result) => {//To subscribe data from Modal
        this.nameList.push(result.name); //Getting error on this line
    });
  }
}
```

Any Help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a Stackblitz? It would be much easier to help you then.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass onReject function when resolving the result promise

```
modalRef.result.then((result) => { 

    /* To subscribe data from Modal */

 }, (reason)=>{ 
 
  /*Leave empty or handle reject*/

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You declaration for namelist is wrong.

You need to declare it like this:
`nameList = [];`

not like this:
`nameList: [];`

Comment: Actually i have a model which is refereed by nameList.
nameList: NameModel[];

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the dismiss like this:

**Component.ts:**

```
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
....

constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal
) {}

modalRef: any;
closeResult: any;

openModal() {
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(SampleModalComponent);
  this.modalRef.result.then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      },
      (reason) => {
        this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
        console.log(this.closeResult);
      });
}

private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
}
```